# (Java) Is there a difference in using OR operator to compare things versus comparing something to each member in an iterated array?

Tags: java

I recently refactored my code to support variable arguments in a method called `searchForBuilding`:

```
public static boolean searchForBuilding(Building[] buildings, ColorEnum ...c) {
    for (Building building : buildings) {
        for (ColorEnum color : c) {
            if (building.getType().getColor() == color) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Previously, I would still loop through the objects I wanted to check, but I'd use the || operator to compare the different BuildingEnums I wanted to evaluate.

```
    for (Building building : BoardTraverser.getAdjacentBuildings(bArray, row, col)) {
        if (building.getType().getColor() == ColorEnum.RED || building.getType().getColor() == ColorEnum.WHITE) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

The resulting change resembles this:

```
return BoardTraverser.searchForBuilding(BoardTraverser.getAdjacentBuildings(bArray, row, col), ColorEnum.RED, ColorEnum.WHITE) ? 2 : 0;
```

Is my new method the same in terms of computational time as comparing things using the OR operator?

Comment: How would you use the `||` operator to do this?

Comment: @Sweeper updated post

Comment: The second code does completely different things! You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: If you want to know about performance, there's no real good way than to measure it; it can be very unintuitive. The first is definitely more readable, so I'd go with that. Can't imagine it making a lot of difference for runtime.

Comment: @Sweeper I fail to see how they do different things. If you look at the third code snippet in my post, you can see how I use searchForBuilding to get a boolean, and use the ternary operator.

Comment: @QuantumBlink Ah okay. I didn't see your third code snippet.